# How do I use an existing Bootstrap Template with NextJS 13.4?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Bootstrap template that contains all the files, e.g. css/js.

How should I go about to import the template into my NextJS application? I read that Global CSS will do the job but can only be imported under `pages/_app.js`, or the `src/app/page.js` in the new NextJS 13.

I have placed my template folder inside `src/theme` and tried importing one of the css files globally like:

```
import "src/theme/css/style.css";
```

However, I'm getting several errors such as some modules not being properly loaded. These errors mainly focuses on the properties that use the `url(../an/image/file)`.

So I'm wondering if I'm actually importing it the wrong way, or is there an alternative way to go about it?

*EDIT*

Error message as follows:

> Failed to compile
> ./src/theme/css/style.css:7:0
> Module not found: Can't resolve '../images/pngs/bg.png'
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
> Import trace for requested module:
> ./src/theme/css/style.css

App structure:

[image]

next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}
module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: Your import seems fine, could you please add the error message and your app structure screenshots so we can identify the actual problem?

Also, if possible please add your next.config.js.